# Query from three tables in C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I've been trying to pull out a combined query of three tables to get some information, but I cannot seem to get it down.

The Query I am looking for would be similar too this

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.Name AS Actor
    FROM Movie AS m
    INNER JOIN MovieEmployees AS me
    ON m.ID = me.movieID
    INNER JOIN Employees AS e
    ON me.employeeID = e.ID
```

My silly coding attempt so far looks like this and it throws errors about conversion types, so I think I am using the wrong variable names.

error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>'` to
>   `'System.Linq.IQueryable<WebApplication2.Entities.Movie>'`. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)    C:\Users\andersona\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Controllers\MoviesController.cs 32  17  WebApplication2

```
IQueryable<Movie> movQuery2 =
     from m in db.Movies
     join me in db.MovieEmployees on m.ID equals me.movieID
     join e in db.Employees on me.employeeID equals e.ID
     select new {Name = e.Name };
```

My Context looks like

```
public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<MovieEmployee> MovieEmployees { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Show> Shows { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<sysdiagram> sysdiagrams { get; set; }
```

And the relationship looks like this

[image]

All I am trying to do is return a query with all three of those tables' data so that I can extract certain items for Views.

i.e. `return View(queryresults);`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if you could briefly explain why your way works or mine doesn't I would be quite thankful as I want to be able to replicate this method for other tables and Views.

Comment: You are trying to get an `IQueryable<Movie>` but just selecting the employee name.  Which is it you want?

Comment: Strike that.  Obvious error is obvious.  An anonymous type is not Movie.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not have any idea what either of you are saying. I am brand to everything above. And the IQuerable was in examples I saw so that is why I was using it. Please give me the correct type if I am using the wrong one. This is new to me, not obvious mistakes. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So either you want a collection of movies or a collection of names.  If you want a collection of Movies:

```
IQueryable<Movie> movQuery2 =
     from m in db.Movies
     join me in db.MovieEmployees on m.ID equals me.movieID
     join e in db.Employees on me.employeeID equals e.ID
     select m;
```

or possible just

```
IQueryable<Movie> movQuery2 =
     from m in db.Movies
     select m;
```

if you want a collection of employee names you could do:

```
IQueryable<string> query = 
     from m in db.Movies
     join me in db.MovieEmployees on m.ID equals me.movieID
     join e in db.Employees on me.employeeID equals e.ID
     select e.Name;
```

or possible just

```
IQueryable<string> query = 
     from me in db.MovieEmployees
     join e in db.Employees on me.employeeID equals e.ID
     select e.Name;
```

To select multiple items you can create an anonymous type:

```
var query = 
     from m in db.Movies
     join me in db.MovieEmployees on m.ID equals me.movieID
     join e in db.Employees on me.employeeID equals e.ID
     select new {e.Name, m.ID};
```

Comment: I actually have one last question, is there any way to select multiple items at the end? I tried adding another select like select e.Name, m.ID; but it says I am missing a semicolon. Is additional syntax needed for multiple selections? Thanks!

Comment: @Austin well most Linq tutorials will have an example of that but I added it to my answer.

Comment: Yea I just figured that out earlier this morning too. Thank you very much!